# How to map with multiple config files

Tags: lua, openwrt, luci

Work on openwrt luci.I have multiple configuration files like: **network** and **wireless** face problem in mapping.I use bellow syntax for mapping

```
m = Map("network", translate("Wireless Settings"))
```

How to map with multiple config files in one model

Answer (score 2):

To work with **map()**,first we need to understand clearly map definition with properties.Here is map definition

```
class Map (config, title, description)
```

This is the root object of the model.

- **config:** configuration name to be mapped, see uci documentation and
  the files in /etc/config
- **title:** title shown in the UI
- **description:** description shown in the UI

you have two config **network** and **wireless**. OK let start multiple config file binding process.First we map with **network** config file then we map with **wireless** config file

Map with **network** config file

```
m = Map("network", translate("Wireless Settings")) -- We want to edit the uci config file /etc/config/network
m:chain("wireless")
s = m:section(NamedSection, "wan", "") -- Especially the "interface"-sections
```

**Note:** m:chain("config") bind second config file

Map with **wireless** config file

```
m1 = Map("wireless","Wireless Network") -- We want to edit the uci config file /etc/config/network
s1 = m1:section(NamedSection,"wifi-iface", "") -- Especially the "interface"-sections
```

for render now we need to return my map model objects

```
return m,m1
```

In this way you can map multiple config files in one model.